# Как добавить ответ бота тг на незабинденные ответы или команды

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
```

async def get_message(message):

```
if message.text == "Получить ссылку":
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = f"*Ваша ссылка:*", reply_markup=keyboard.dryg, parse_mode='Markdown')
```

Пример кода, на который бот знает что ответить, если ему человек вводит например : «Автлвлла» этого нет в хендлерах, как сделать так, чтобы бот ответил человеку «я не знаю такой команды»

Answer (score 0):

```py
if message.text == "Получить ссылку":
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = f"*Ваша ссылка:*", reply_markup=keyboard.dryg, parse_mode='Markdown')
else:
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text = "Я не знаю такой команды")
```

Answer (score 0):

В целом просто сделай пустой хендлер

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def none_func(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer("Я хз что это значит...")
```

И этот хендлер должен быть самым последним, иначе другие хендлеры могут быть проигнорированы